# ContactResultsData.DataContext not found

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-phone-8

i want to get all my phone contacts in a list so i'm using those libraries and the *ID_CAP_CONTACTS* is checked in the **WMAppManifest.xaml**

> ```
> using System;
> using System.Collections.Generic;
> using System.Linq;
> using System.Net;
> using System.Windows;
> using System.Windows.Controls;
> using System.Windows.Navigation;
> using Microsoft.Phone.Controls;
> using System.Windows.Input;
> using Microsoft.Phone.Shell;
> using Microsoft.Phone.UserData;
> ```

but in my code the **ContactResultsData.DataContext** is not found

```
public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Contacts objContacts = new Contacts();
            objContacts.SearchCompleted += new EventHandler<ContactsSearchEventArgs>(objContacts_SearchCompleted);
            objContacts.SearchAsync(string.Empty, FilterKind.None, null);
        }

        void objContacts_SearchCompleted(object sender, ContactsSearchEventArgs e)
        {
            List<CustomContact> listOfContacts = new List<CustomContact>();
            foreach (var result in e.Results)
            {
                CustomContact contact = new CustomContact();
                contact.DisplayName = result.DisplayName;
                var number = result.PhoneNumbers.FirstOrDefault();
                if (number != null)
                    contact.Number = number.PhoneNumber;
                else
                    contact.Number = "";

                listOfContacts.Add(contact);

                }
                ContactResultsData.DataContext = listOfContacts;
            }


        }
        private void ContactResultsData_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            Contact contact = ContactResultsData.SelectedItem as Contact;
            if (contact != null)
            {
                CustomContact customContact = new CustomContact(contact);
            }
        }
```

what is the problem what it needs please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i forget to add the ListBox **ContactResultsData**

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
            <StackPanel Height="Auto" Width="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,0,0,10" >

                <TextBlock Name="ContactResultsLabel" Text="results are loading..." Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextLargeStyle}" TextWrapping="Wrap" />

                <ListBox Name="ContactResultsData" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Height="436" Margin="12,0" SelectionMode="Multiple" >
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Name="ContactResults" FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeMedium}" Text="{Binding Path=DisplayName, Mode=OneWay}" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ListBox>
            </StackPanel>

        </Grid>
```